# Items from bootstrap dropdown don't align horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why this code:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

    </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.dropdown-menu li {
    display: inline;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Still doesn't makes the list horizontally aligned? I can't figure the reason...
This is driving me crazy!

http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/1440c8a6/

EDIT: Note the full html code is at jsfiddle, I didn't paste it here because it is too large.

Comment: Do you want all the links on the dropdown align like this:
Action | Another Action | etc ?

Comment: it's hard to know what you expect from the code, the secondary menu is a bit off, but that's because you have `height: 40px;`, if you remove that, the dropdown items will have an even size. If you want to have more space between them, use `padding top/bottom` instead of `height`.

Comment: @Pirata21 exactly! THAT!

Comment: Don't see anything wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, isn't a common behavior but to do that, you must give more width to the container(ul.dropdown-menu), after that if the list items are floating you would see the menu horizontal

```
ul.dropdown-menu li {
   float:left;
   padding: 0px;
}

ul.dropdown-menu {
   width: 600px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1440c8a6/3/

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to make your menu items bigger, remove the `height` from your `li` and use padding on the `top` and `bottom` at the `a` element:

```
ul.dropdown-menu li {
    display: inline;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.dropdown-menu li a{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here is your changed fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LL2nyuyL/